# How can I browse some document-like apps offline?

Tags: offline, ebooks, documents

Some Android apps are actually some kind of documents/ebooks, but it seems that I can't browse it offline. for example, it seems that when my phone is not connected to a network or mobile data service, the following app doesn't load

- [LeetCode Cracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.zhujiaqi.leetcode)

How can I browse such apps offline?

Thanks.

Comment: I can only provide a specific solution to this app since I'm not sure if there's a general solution for all apps like this.

Answer (score 3):

The app doesn't save anything, and it's using in-app browser to load the codes from GitHub repository. From its app description,

> **All of my solution files are on GitHub, and are in Java.** It contains almost all of the problems of LeetCode except some of them I haven't came up with a good solution. **Since this app read files from GitHub repository, it requires network connection.** I think this will not require too much data usage. And it make it easy for me to update solutions without update this app.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Searching based on it returned [the corresponding GitHub repository](https://github.com/softstar1990/LeetCode).

Now, given the GitHub repository, the next step is to clone it to the device (e.g. for offline usage). As of current, I only found and tested [SGit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.sheimi.sgit), and it worked for me.

Usage:

1. Install and open SGit
2. Tap *Clone* (plus icon) on the top bar
3. For *Remote URL*, input `https://github.com/softstar1990/LeetCode`.
   For *Local Path*, input anything that can be used as identifier (e.g. `LeetCode`).
4. Tap *Clone*. The cloned repository will be stored on: `[sdcard dir]/Android/data/me.sheimi.sgit/files/repo/[Local Path]`
5. Browse the repository from SGit offline.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to convert a document/ebook like app to a pdf file in general ? see http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6683/convert-an-android-app-which-is-actually-an-ebook-to-a-pdf-file